# Is there a way to prevent Shiny from referencing Bootstrap 3 shared folder?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am attempting to use my own bootstrap style sheet after compiling it with sass. Using

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = 'mybootstrap.min.css', ...)
```

Most of the variables I changed within _variables.scss and then compiled are working but there are a few exceptions. One is the `tabsetPanel` is defaulting to using a folder named "shared" for a dependency on Bootstrap version 3. This is preventing the primary color that I set from being used.

Is there a way to override this default behavior so that Shiny uses the compiled version of bootstrap that I want?

Comment: try [bslib](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/)

Comment: I am aware of bslib but I'm looking for a solution that uses a compiled css from outside of R.

Answer (score 0):

I see, there is no good way to remove bootstrap resources from a `fluidPage`. Here I provide you 2 solutions.

1. use a simple `div` instead of `fluidPage` as the container, like this:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- div(
  tags$script(src = "mybs.min.js"),
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "mybs.min.css")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Attach your custom bs scripts and CSS files manually.

2. overwrite the the internals of `fluidPage`

```r
library(shiny)
bootstrapPage <- function (..., title = NULL, theme = NULL, lang = NULL) {
    args <- list(jqueryDependency(), if (!is.null(title)) tags$head(tags$title(title)),
                 if (is.character(theme)) {
                     if (length(theme) > 1) stop("`theme` must point to a single CSS file, not multiple files.")
                     tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css",
                                         href = theme))
                 }, list2(...))
    if (is_bs_theme(theme)) {
        args <- c(bootstrapLib(theme), args)
        ui <- do.call(tagList, args)
    }
    else {
        ui <- do.call(tagList, args)
        # ui <- attachDependencies(ui, bootstrapLib())
    }
    setLang(ui, lang)
}

environment(bootstrapPage) <- asNamespace('shiny')
assignInNamespace("bootstrapPage", bootstrapPage, ns = "shiny")


ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = "abc.css"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is very hacky and personally not recommended unless you are an advanced user and clear the consequences. so not going to details, just let you know it will work. You can see no bs resources attached and the custom CSS `abc.css` is attached.

[image]

### updates

here is the full code if you want use custom version of bootstrap

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- div(
  HTML(
    '
    <!-- You dont want include this CDN of css, in your case, use your own CSS, remove the following line.-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Remember the JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    '
  ),
  tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href=""), # your own css file here
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
      tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
      tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Using the first method does this render functions like `tabsetPanel` useless? Even if I use the cdn version of a bootswatch theme as you show, elements like tab pills are not rendering correctly.

Comment: Because you didn't attach the js CDN file, see my updates